# How to add a tag? QBE (with it being a synonym for query-by-example) in this case

Tags: feature-request

Can someone add the tag(s) "qbe" and/or "query-by-example" and, if adding both, make one the synonym of the other (not sure which order, but I'm sure there's a practice for it)?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_by_Example

Comment: You have enough rep to [create tags](http://dba.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) on your own questions